# java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object while Iterating For Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, classcastexception

I am getting a `classcast` exception while i am iterating my for loop.

This is my code:

```
List<Object[]> objList = myDao.getList(bookId, bookName);
for(Object[] t : objList )
{       
    if(!myClass.isBlank((String)t[1]))
    {
        bookList.add(new book((String) t[0],(String) t[0]));
    }
}
```

Below is the output i get in my `objList`

```
[Potter, GOT]
```

Exception while entering for Loop

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object

What i tried again was to change my for loop as below but it still didnt worked.

```
List<Object[]> objList = myManager.getList(bookId, bookName);
String[] bookObj = new String[objList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < objList.size(); i++) {

    if(!myClass.isBlank((String)bookObj[i])){
        bookList.add(new SelectItem((String) bookObj[i],(String) bookObj[i]));
    }
}
```

Can anyone please guide whats wrong.

Comment: It looks like `myDao.getList()` returns a `List<String>` and not a `List<Object[]>`.

Comment: you are such a lucky guy that Jon Skeet edited your post.!! :D

as Eran mentioned, return type of dao method getList() might be String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank @Eran for the hint.

I solved it by doing the below. As @Eran said it was returning `List<String>`

```
List<String> objList = myManager.getList(bookId, bookName);
for(String t : objList)
{       
    if(!StringUtil.isBlank((String)t))
    {
        bookList.add(new book((String) t,(String) t));
    }
}
```

Comment: How did it compile?  Does `getList` return a raw type?  Yuck.

Comment: @ajb : It was returning a raw type. I corrected it as above.